# Laravel php artisan key:generate in production

Tags: php, laravel

On my production server I set the env var `APP_ENV=production`. With this config laravel will not use .env file but it will use env var declared on the server.

But I have a problem when I run this command `php artisan key:generate` because I'll get this error:

```
In KeyGenerateCommand.php line 96:
                                                                               
  file_get_contents(/app/.env): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Just for this command laravel need the .env file. So actually I create an empty .env file to make it works but it's ugly...

Do you have any solution ? or maybe this command is useless in production env ?

Comment: not using a .env file is not typical in Laravel so yes `php artisan key:generate` is pretty useless to you.

Comment: @apokryfos I tested to run my app without this command but I got an error `Class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found`

Comment: you do need to generate the key somehow. Generating it locally on a temporary .env file and adding the result to your production environment config would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push a Laravel project to production, you need to generate a `.env` file, since that file is not committed. You *should* have a `.env.example`, which you can copy and modify as required:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Then you can run `php artisan key:generate` to set the App Key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ok so it's required to get a .env file. Does this .env file will override my env var set on my server ?

Comment: Potentially, but from my experience, env variables on the server should only come from this `.env` file. They are loaded into Laravel via the various `config/{file}.php` files. And yes, a `.env` file is almost always required. It's entirely possible to run Laravel without a `.env` file (or an empty one), but you'd have to hard-code _everything_ into those files, which is a large security issue, since those files are committed to repositories by default.

Comment: Actually I'm running on Cloud Run, it's serverless, so I can only use env var declared in Cloud Run. So I can't create the .env on the server I have to use env vars from Cloud Run . That is why I'm using `APP_ENV=production` to use env vars from the server. So if it's not possible to execute `php artisan key:generate` without .env I'll create an empty .env thank you

Comment: Ah gotcha. I've seen something similar, not with CloudRun, but a different app with a Secrets Manager. The way we handled that was having a deploy step that writes the `.env` file from these secrets, but if you're defining them at run-time (or via Server vars, etc), that works too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this :

```
sudo php artisan key:generate
```

Before doing it make sure you are in the folder, for example :

```
cd /var/www/html/your_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `.env` files in production you can pass `--show` to the `key:generate` command to only print it and the store it in an environment variable:

```
$ APP_KEY=$(php artisan key:generate --show --no-interaction)
```